Grid node not able to access testing client/host's web server
I am deploying Selenium Grid with one Hub(public) and several Nodes(private IPs). Now I am running test script on my machine which will test the web server that I run on locally on my machine.
In the testing script I will need to test against my local server so I will have somehting like driver.get("http://localhost:8080"). But since the test is running on the Selenium Grid Nodes hosts, how to make the the Node hosts access my local machine's web server?

you can't...  run the test locally.
